# Using Shark with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-hadoop

Have anyone used Shark as repository from resulting datasets from Apache Spark?

I'm starting some tests with Spark and read about this database tecnology. Have anyone been using it?

Comment: Use SparkSQL, Shark is deprecated.

Comment: @samthebeast can you provide a reference?

Comment: I tried Shark a few weeks ago. I was able to get it running using their documentation and a lot of sweat. I ultimately gave up on it as I was trying to pull/push data from s3 and I couldn't find a way to do that. We since switched to Impala.

Comment: I got it! I'll try to make some tests with SparkSQL to see if I feel confortable with that.

Comment: @gallamine http://databricks.com/blog/2014/07/01/shark-spark-sql-hive-on-spark-and-the-future-of-sql-on-spark.html

Comment: This doesn't make a great question. I'd rephrase to ask about specific issues you have in mind.

Comment: This is my issue! I nerd a technology to stage my resulting data from spark as I asked before. Thanks folks! I'm getting great results from it!